# Updating both rows and columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Can rows be upadted along with the colums for a table.
I had a table where amount was to be updated for single member for 3 different years

I used the following query

```
update ahd
   set amount1=(select a.amnt1
                  from ahd inner join ahdtmp a on ahd.member_key=a.member_key
                 where ahd.date1=a.date1
                   and a.status='FALSE'
                   and a.member_key in (select distinct member_key
                                          from ahd))
```

When I execute this

> ERROR at line 2:
>   ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

The temporary table is ahdtmp

```
create table ahdtmp(
member_key number(10),
date1 date,
amnt1 number(10,2),
amnt2 number(10,2),
date_amend date,
Status varchar2(10));
```

Please suggest on this?

What could have gone wrong..

Comment: The subquery you have after `set amount1 = ...` is returning more than one row whereas it is supposed to return one or zero rows. Check your subquery and modify it so that it returns only one row.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly what you want is:

```
update ahd
set amount1=(select a.amnt1
              from ahdtmp a
             where ahd.member_key=a.member_key and
                   ahd.date1     =a.date1
               and a.status='FALSE')
where  member_key = 'some particlar member ey'
```

Comment: But this will update all rows of the table, putting NULL values where the subquery finds no match. Right? I see that the OP's statement would do the same (if it worked) but I guess he wouldn't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following script will be useful, is a generic code (its only an example):

```
CREATE TABLE SOURCE(
  s_key int,
  s_name varchar2(100));

CREATE TABLE TARGET(
  t_key int,
  t_name varchar2(100));


INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(1,'A');
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(2,'B');
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(3,'C');
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(4,'D');

INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(1,'Z');
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(2,'Z');
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(3,'Z');
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(4,'Z');

/*HERE THE CODE*/   
MERGE
INTO    target
USING   (
        SELECT  s.s_name,s.s_key
        FROM    source s
        )
ON      (t_key = s_key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     t_name = s_name;
```

Here the link to try this example (it works fine) **[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed106/2)**.

I not sure but your query would be something like this:

```
MERGE
INTO    ahd
USING   (
        SELECT a.amnt1
        FROM ahdtmp a
        )
ON      (ahd.member_key=a.member_key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     amount1 = amnt1
WHERE ahd.status='FALSE'
    AND ahd.member_key IN (SELECT DISTINCT member_key FROM ahd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is sub query returns multiple values. You have to filter it to return single record.

```
update ahd
set amount1=(select a.amnt1
              from ahd inner join ahdtmp a on ahd.member_key=a.member_key
             where ahd.date1=a.date1
               and a.status='FALSE'
               and a.member_key ='user_specific_key')
```